# SQL Scanning Previous Records in Database

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider the table

```
          Index    Col_1    Col_2   Value_of_Interest
Record_1    1
Record_2    2
   .
   .
   .
Record_N    N
```

I want to select the set of records `{Record_i}` such that `Col_1` of `Record_i+1` exists in `{SELECT Col_2 FROM table WHERE Index<i}`

For example, consider the table

```
          Index    Col_1    Col_2   Value_of_Interest
Record_1    1       Ed      Bill           1
Record_2    2      James    Rob            0
Record_3    3       Tom     Rob            1
Record_4    4      Bill     Rob            0
```

The query would return

```
          Index    Col_1    Col_2   Value_of_Interest
Record_3    3       Tom     Rob            1
```

As `Col_1` of `Record_4` is `Bill` and this is contained in `Col_2` of a previous record.

Is it possible to write a SQL query that performs this?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question in English?

Comment: Lol, I'll have another go at explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable AS T1
WHERE (SELECT Col_1
       FROM MyTable AS T2
       WHERE T2.Index = T1.Index + 1
      ) IN (SELECT Col_2
            FROM MyTable AS T3
            WHERE T3.Index < T1.Index)
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cfc9/13)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Index` int, `Col_1` varchar(5), `Col_2` varchar(4), `Value_of_Interest` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Index`, `Col_1`, `Col_2`, `Value_of_Interest`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Ed', 'Bill', 1),
    (2, 'James', 'Rob', 0),
    (3, 'Tom', 'Rob', 1),
    (4, 'Bill', 'Rob', 0)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.`Index`, t1.Col_1, t1.Col_2, t1.Value_of_Interest
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.`index` =
(SELECT t2.`index`-1
FROM Table1 t2
WHERE t2.Col_1 IN 
     (SELECT Col_2 FROM Table1 t3 WHERE t3.`Index` < t2.`Index`))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cfc9/13/0)**:

```
| INDEX | COL_1 | COL_2 | VALUE_OF_INTEREST |
|-------|-------|-------|-------------------|
|     3 |   Tom |   Rob |                 1 |
```

Comment: And why are you using MySQL?

Comment: Oupsss....didn't see that there is a SQLite in SQLFIDDLE...but it's basic SQL...so it works...may be just the ```